# Can I make origin/dev branch of origin/staging when origin/dev already exists?

Tags: git

I'd like to reclaim the `dev` branch, but it's filled with things we don't want to keep. Can I make it just stop being whatever it is now and be based of staging instead without deleting the history that's in it? I'd like to set things up like this:

```
staging __________________________________
dev     _________  \______/    \____/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "based off of staging" and "without deleting the history".

If you mean that you want to act like you merged `dev` and `staging` together, but actually have the end result be exactly what is currently in staging, that's easy. From the root directory of the repository:

```
git checkout origin/dev -b dev
git merge --no-commit origin/staging
git checkout --theirs .
git commit -m "Revert back to the contents of staging"
git push origin dev
```

The key line here is the third one. It's what overwrites the result of the merge with the exact contents of the `origin/staging` branch.

Answer (score 0):

A branch is only a reference to a commit.  If you feel like getting rid of the `dev` branch, then in your local repository do

```
$ git branch -D dev
$ git branch dev staging
```

The first command deletes the branch "dev" and the second creates it again forking it off "staging" so that "dev" branch ends up pointing to the same commit "staging" does.

If you sync with a remote repo, you will need to do *forced* push of the new "dev" branch:

```
$ git push --force origin dev
```

If you still need to preserve the history "dev" contains now, rename it instead of deleting:

```
$ git branch -m dev ex-dev
```

The point about forced pushing the new "dev" obviously still holds in this case.

Note that forced replacement of a branch in the remote repository has significant repercussions for those who cloned the repo before such replacement and based their local branches on the original contents of he now-replaced branch.  This is widely covered in the literature.  See `git-rebase` manual for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question's a little confusing in that it says "things we don't want to keep", but then "without deleting the history". To err on the side of caution, I would recommend:

```
git checkout staging #switch away from dev branch
git branch -m dev olddev #rename old dev branch so we don't delete history
git checkout -b dev staging # start a new dev branch where staging is currently
```

If you want to start the new `dev` branch at a different point, just substitute the appropriate SHA1 or branch name for `staging` in the last command. If you want `dev` to be a completely new branch with no parents, you'll need the `--orphan` option to `git checkout`.

Once you've done that, see kostix notes about pushing the new `dev` to an upstream repository.